# Using threadprivate directive in Visual Studio

Tags: c, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, openmp, extern

It appears that OpenMP implementation in Visual Studio 2010 has a serious bug that does not allow to have external variables as threadprivate. The the following code would not compile:

file.c

---

```
#include <omp.h>

/* Declaration of external variable. */

extern int My_Var;

#pragma omp threadprivate (My_Var) 

void MyFunc(void) { My_Var = 1;}
```

---

The error message is:

```
error C3053:
'My_Var' : 'threadprivate' is only valid for global or static data tems.
```

Clearly the compiler is confused about linkage attribute of the variable.

It is most common to refer global variables in multiple files. So this problem makes `threadprivate` directive unusable in any realistic program.

I wonder if there are tricks to handle this bug. Unfortunately in my case this problem prevents me to use OMP completely.

Thank you,

Alex

Comment: have you tried compiling with `/openmp /LD` ?

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a (yet another) violation of the OpenMP standard in the VC++ compiler. Fortunately the `threadprivate` clause in VC++ is implemented directly as the application of the `thread` `__declspec` attribute and you can simply replace:

```
extern int My_Var;

#pragma omp threadprivate (My_Var)
```

with

```
extern __declspec(thread) int My_Var;
```

Still you have to provide the same `__declspec(thread)` attribute (or `#pragma omp threadprivate` pragma) to `My_Var` in all translation units where it is declared (as is also required per the OpenMP specification - Section 2.7.1 of the "OpenMP 2.0" specs).

Comment: I just used extern __declspec(thread) int My_Var; as suggest and it all compiled fine.